# Define a model in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've created the following node module to define my model. Is this a reasonable approach?

**Model.js:**

```
var dynamoose = require('dynamoose');

var product = dynamoose.model('Product', { id: Number, name: String });
var giftCard = dynamoose.model('GiftCard', { id: Number, name: String });

exports.product = product;
exports.giftCard = giftCard;
```

**index.js:**

```
var m = require('model');
var coffeeMug = new m.product('1111','Coffee Mug')
console.log(coffeeMug);
```

Comment: You should explain in more detail that you're using [*Dynamoose*](https://github.com/automategreen/dynamoose), because its way of creating models is a bit different from the "default" Node.js way. I would also recommend to instantiate objects like this: `new m.product({id: '1111', name: 'Coffee Mug'})`. It increases readability and you and other developers will always know which properties are actually set.